# Setting Other Child's Property On Hover Under Same Parent With Pure CSS (HTML List)

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

I'm trying to make a CSS menu with submenus. When I move the mouse over a child element of list, I want the submenu to appear inside that child if there is any.

[image: problem description]
As it is avaliable to see above, sub menu appears but I don't want that to happen when I move the cursor over the areas that I've marked with circles. These are padding areas.

Here's my markup:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="/mission">Our Mission</a></li>
         <li><a href="/vision">Our Vision</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
a { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color: #A0A0A0; }
ul > li { float: left; padding: 0px 30px; list-style-type: none;  
          margin: 0px 5px; background-color: #CACACA; }
ul > li:hover > ul { display: inline; }
ul > li > ul { position: fixed; display: none; }
```

Now there is no problem with this code. As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/confeng/H5hs2/), it works as I wanted, the submenu appears when I move the mouse over the "About Us" menu.

However, my problem here is that there are blank spaces(padding) inside menu items and the submenu appears even if I hover over these spaces. But I want the submenu to appear only when I hover the `<a>` element inside the `<li>`.

To accomplish this, I tried that code:

```
ul > li > a:hover > ul { display: inline; }
```

instead of the existing:

```
ul > li:hover > ul { display: inline; }
```

but it didn't work, I wasn't expecting since the `<a>` and `<ul>` are the children of the very same `<li>` element.

I'm creating a template for a CMS, so I don't want to get involved with jQuery implementations too much, like setting `id`s or `class`es for list elements. I want to make an implementation with pure CSS.

And I will be using seperating images between list elements, so I must use `padding` instead of `margin`.

If I was using `margin`, it would be easy since the `width` of the list element would be same with the `<a>` element's `width`.

But here, after all these exceptions, I need some help. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. Could you try to re-explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Of course, I've added a screenshot. I hope it looks more clear now.

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense. You were so, so, close. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but only-just, and with some fairly severe caveats; first the CSS to hide/show the sub-menu:

```
ul > li > ul {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
ul > li a:hover + ul,
ul > li:hover a + ul:hover{
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/H5hs2/4/).

Now, the caveats:

1. The `display` property won't animate (it can't, there's no interim states between `none` and `inline-block` (or between any other valid values for the property), so the sub-menu always has to be 'visible'/'present' on the page (albeit with an opacity of `0` hiding it in most browsers).
2. The transitions are necessary, because that's the only way that the cursor would have time to move from the `a` link to the `ul` without it immediately hiding; the transition is, basically, a time-delay to allow the second of the selectors, `ul > li:hover a + ul:hover` to match.
3. cross-browser compatibility is likely to be a problem, since `transitions` aren't supported in Internet Explorer < 10, mind you nor is opacity until version 9.
4. The major problem, though, is selector specificity. It's going to be rather difficult to write the selectors for arbitrary-depth menus using this technique. So, while it's *possible*, I certainly wouldn't recommend *using* this approach, as it seems far too prone to failure.

Comment: To accomplish the very basic markup, I didn't want to involve transitions. However I agree with the necessitation. Otherwise, I had to place the ul element right below the parent, with no margin. This code works just fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier way to do this would be to use the CSS peer selector `+`. Because the sub-menu `<ul>` is not a direct child of the `<a>` tag, you can't use `>`. Instead use the peer selector `+` to choose all *subsequent* peers of a particular type.

In other words: `ul li a:hover + ul { display: inline; }`

And it has [good browser support.](http://caniuse.com/#search=selector+)

Comment: Yeah, it seems that I was just missing the theory. Thanks for the good explanation.